# Uniformly sampling principal component scores to explore response surface

Tags: sampling, pca, dimensionality-reduction

**New simpler version of the question**

Consider a sample $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^p$ with $p$ small, say $p=5$, and $n$ large, say $n=3000$.
Because they are actually scores of principal components, the columns of $\mathbf{X}$ are uncorrelated.
I would like to sample uniformly the domain *covered* by the rows of $\mathbf{X}$.
The meaning of “covered” here is not formally defined. The resulting sample should explore as efficiently as possible the domain of possible realisations of the scores. For instance, a point clearly outside of the convex hull of $\mathbf{X}$ is probably useless.

---

> **Older version with more context**
>
> Consider a model $y = f(\mathbf{x})$ with $f: \mathbb{R}^p \mapsto
>  \mathbb{R}$. The components of $\mathbf{x}$ are correlated. More
>   precisely, $\mathbf{x}$ is of functional nature, say time series or
>   power spectra.
>
> I am interested into the sum of the responses of the model $f$ to a
>   big sample of inputs $\mathbf{X}$ : $\sum_{\mathbf{x}_i \in
>  \mathbf{X}} f(\mathbf{x}_i)$ However, $f$ is very expensive and only a
>   few dozens of evalutations are feasible.
>
> Because the elements of $\mathbf{X}$ all share an air of ressemblance,
>   I reduced the input dimension to something low (say 5) using principal
>   component analysis.
>
> Now I would like to explore the response surface of the model $f$. For
>   that purpose, I need to sample the 5 principal component scores I
>   retained with a space filling design of experiment, a low discrepancy
>   sequence or a Latin hypercube. As I want to characterise the whole
>   reponse surface, I am inclined to sample them uniformly. I could also
>   use their empirical marginal distributions inferred from $\mathbf{X}$.
>   Their is no correlation to account for because they are principal
>   component scores, and are thus uncorrelated. However, they still
>   relate to one another in the sense that the empirical sample
>   $\mathbf{X}$ covers a restricted domain of the input space, which is
>   the region of interest. What strategy would you recommend to sample
>   the principal components scores in an efficient manner while enforcing
>   this restriction?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Your PC scores form a cloud of points in $\mathbb R^5$. Do you want to sample from this cloud such that the whole extent of the cloud is sampled uniformly (as opposed to directly sampling the random points in this cloud, which would sample according to the density)?

Comment: @amoeba Yes, that is what I have in mind.

Comment: Then this does not have much to do with PCA, of $f$, or anything else. Perhaps if you rewrite your question to focus it specifically on this sampling issue, you will have higher chances to get a good reply.

Comment: @amoeba You are right, I'll do it as soon as possible.